# Copy image code not working with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

lets say on a test page i have just the following:

```
copy('http://media.fastcar.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Stanced-Mazda-MX5-Miata-10.jpg', 'images/covers/file5.jpeg');
```

If i load this page the image is copied and saved correctly.

However, the input for the url is on a page where other data is also taken from and then inserted in the db.

For that im using javascript validation and then redirect the user on success to another page.

The php looks like this:

```
try {

$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO blogs (blogtitle, blogdesc, coverimage, userID, frontpage, tags) 
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
if ($statement->execute(array($_POST['addbuildtitle'], $_POST['addbuilddesc'], $_POST['addbuildcover'], $_POST['adduserid'], $frontpage,    $_POST['addtags'])));
    $dbSuccess = true;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $return['databaseException'] = $e->getMessage();
}

$return['databaseSuccess'] = $dbSuccess;
$return['lastid'] = $db->lastInsertId();

    copy('http://media.fastcar.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Stanced-Mazda-MX5-Miata-10.jpg', 'images/covers/file5.jpeg');

echo json_encode($return);
```

}

When i put the code after the $return array things, nothing happens.

I tested the php page with just the copy code and it still didnt work so i cant see how to get it working with the ajax call.

Is there a way around this or is it possible to put it in the javascript side of things?

Comment: I don’t see you using copy in your code, and I also can’t see what this has to do with AJAX.

Comment: have added it in where i was trying it, but dont know where to properly put it...

Comment: Now the source URL and destination filename are hardcoded in there – this can hardly be what you want, because it should be enough to do this only once I guess. What you actually want, and how it is connected to your _“page where other data is also taken from”_, the database and AJAX is still unclear …

Comment: check folder permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with full destination path

```
copy('http://media.fastcar.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Stanced-Mazda-MX5-Miata-10.jpg', '/home/Path-to-image-folder/file5.jpeg');
```